# Remove the comment flag rate limit when flagging comments on the same post

Tags: feature-request, comments, comment-flags, rate-limiting

In [Can we remove the 5 second rate limiting on comment flags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/299103/can-we-remove-the-5-second-rate-limiting-on-comment-flags), a [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) tag was thrown on a request to remove the 5-second rate limit entirely. The reason provided was that abuse becomes more difficult to handle when no rate limit exists.

I think there's a pretty simple solution to this question: if and *only* if you're flagging multiple comments on the same post, do not rate-limit the flagger. This means someone who wants to go through and flag 5/20 comments in one conversation on a post doesn't have to wait 30 seconds to do it. But the next time someone tries to flag comments on a *different* post, the 5-second rate limit applies.

The most common use case for comment flags that I've seen flags multiple comments on the same post. I struggle to see why someone who wants to flag a specific comment thread should be rate-limited, and I really don't see the abuse case here. With both a limit on the number of comments one can flag at once, and the number of flags one can raise, it becomes the same case as [being rate-limited while deleting comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14185/deleting-a-comment-mine-shouldnt-count-as-a-comment-vote).

This would also enable people to flag multiple comments in a thread more easily, particularly when it's not necessary to flag the *whole* post, which is also a plus.

Comment: prior to removal of delay (or even instead of it) I would prefer to test just a decrease of it, to something like 2-3 seconds. I feel that _some_ delay is beneficial: even though I usually read whole conversation and make my picks and could in theory flag them at unlimited rate I would feel safer with some delay to help avoid mis-clicks. It is just that 5 seconds delay seems a bit too much for that

Comment: If a post has several comments that are flag-worthy, isn't it better to flag the post itself instead for mod attention? That way it will be only 1 flag to handle, versus 1 flag per comment...

Comment: @DarkCygnus It's more convenient for moderators if you flag each comment individually when there are a subset of obsolete comments in a larger set. (At least, it's easier for me, that way.)

Comment: @Zyerah noted, will keep it in mind for next time I see several flaggeable content :)